# Как передать аргументы в конструктор при выделении памяти для массива объектов?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть структура:

```
struct A{
    char * buf;

    A(int size){
        buf = new char[size];
    }
};
```

Хочу создать массив объектов `A` с указанным размером.

```
A * a = new A[10](10); // 10 объектов, должны конструироваться через A(int size)
```

но никак не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нет уж очень принципиальной потребности полагаться на  сырые `new`, то можно использовать `std::vector` и один из его конструкторов:

```
std::vector<A> v(10, A(10));
```

Правда в этом случае объект создается указанным конструктором один раз, а далее уже происходит копирование. То есть нужно написать подходящий копирующий конструктор.

Answer (score 1):

Сильно подозреваю, что UB, но можно попорбовать что-то такое: https://ideone.com/PlWjPh

```
struct A
{
  char *buf;
  A(int size) : buf(new char[size]) {}
  ~A() { delete [] buf; }
};

template <typename T, int val> struct with_arg : T
{
  with_arg() : T(val) {}
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new with_arg <A, 10> [10];
  delete [] a;
  return 0;
}
```

Обсуждение наличия UB в этом коде:

- [Можно ли игнорировать пустого наследника при арифметике указателей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764692/178988)
- [Можно ли игнорировать пустого наследника при написании деструктора?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764696/178988)

Comment: Конечно UB! Как минимум деструктор должен быть виртуальным.

Comment: @alexolut, тут потенциально 2 UB - деструктор и неверный тип массива. Но класс-наследник ничего не добавляет, поэтому может оказаться и нормальным.

Comment: про неверный тип массива не понял. А для UB не важно, добавляет там что-то новый класс или нет, если удаляются объекты производного класса через указатель на базовый, то без виртуального деструктора в базовом классе тут будет UB.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <new>

int main()
{
    struct A{
        ~A() { delete [] buf; buf = nullptr; }
        A( int size ) { buf = new char[ size ]; }

        char * buf;
    }; 
    //выделяем
    A* ptr = (A*)(::operator new[](sizeof(A) * 10));
    for(auto i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        new(ptr + i) A(10);
    }
    //освобождаем
    for(auto i=0; i<10; ++i)
        (ptr + i)->~A();
    ::operator delete[](ptr, sizeof(A)*10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот это перверсия...

Comment: это ж не эталонный код какой-то... просто показал автору что он хочет

Answer (score 0):

```
//еще вариант
int main()
{
    //___
    A* aptr = static_cast<A*>(operator new [](sizeof(A) * 10));
    //___        
}

//и еще        
template <size_t  i>
struct A{
    char * buf;
    A(){
        buf = new char[i + 1];
    }
};

int main()
{

    A* p = new A<10>[10];
    p[0].buf[0] = 't';  
    //_ _ _
}
```