# Можно ли игнорировать пустого наследника при арифметике указателей?

Tags: c++, наследование, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Есть класс `A`, от которого наследуется класс `B`. Однако, класс `B` не содержит никаких полей. Если я создам массив элементов `B`, но использую его как массив элементов `A`, то будет ли это корректно?

[В стандарте говорится](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4), что это разрешено только с *подобными* типами:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements,86 the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element 
>   x
>   [
>   i
>   +
>   j
>   ]
>    if 
>   0
>   ≤
>   i
>   +
>   j
>   ≤
>   n
>   ; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element 
>   x
>   [
>   i
>   −
>   j
>   ]
>    if 
>   0
>   ≤
>   i
>   −
>   j
>   ≤
>   n
>   ; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

*Подобность* типов описана [рядом](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#def:similar_types), но я не могу понять, являются ли в моём случае типы подобными. Какие именно типы считаются подобными?

Вот пример кода: <s>https://ideone.com/ncRepZ</s> https://ideone.com/nMvJ0r
Содержит ли он неопределённое поведение?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
  int x;
  A(int x) : x(x) {}
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : A
{
  B() : A(7) {}
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new B[4];

  for (size_t q=0; q<4; ++q)
    cout << q << ": " << a[q].x << endl;

  delete [] a;

  return 0;
}
```

В случае, если это всё-таки не разрешено, достаточно ли добавить проверку на равенство размеров этих двух типов https://ideone.com/iSkJk0

```
static_assert(sizeof (A) == sizeof (B), "B must have same size as A");
```

чтобы гарантировать, что если программа компилируется, то она не содержит UB?

Comment: Вы замечание в пункте [expr.add / 6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6) смотрели?

Comment: In particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type

Comment: @wololo, но там же _"where T and the array element type are not similar"_

Comment: Я бы для начала рекомендовал убрать из кода использование кучи, или хотя бы `delete`, чтобы не накладывать один UB на другой.

Comment: @alexolut, а с delete что не так? Деструкторов тут нет же?

Comment: Так их система генерит по дефолту и они не `virtual`.

Comment: @alexolut, напиши тогда тут ответом, если уверен? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764922/178988

Comment: @alexolut, поправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По второй ссылке ясно написано, что типы подобны, если они совпадают с точностью до const и volatile, а также замены массива фиксированного размера на массив неизвестного размера:

> Two types T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> are similar if they have cv-decompositions with the same n such that corresponding P<sub>i</sub> components are either the same or one is “array of N<sub>i</sub>” and the other is “array of unknown bound of”, and the types denoted by U are the same.

Преобразования между наследником и базовым типом в отношение подобия не входят.

Так что формально так делать нельзя, будет UB. На практике проявиться это UB может так же, как и любое другое нарушение strict aliasing rule:

```cpp
A *a = new B[4];
a[1].x = 5;

B *b = (B*)a;
(b+1)->x = 6;

std::cout << a[1].x << std::endl; // Слишком умный компилятор выведет 5
```

Comment: Впрочем, в приведённом примере и всех его вариациях, которые я смог придумать (убрать присваивание b[1].x, поменять индекс, убрать оба присваивания a[1].x и b[1].x), gcc вообще сносит создание массива и инлайнит правильную константу (5, 6 или 7). Clang ведёт себя так же, но в случае с удалением обоих присваиваний оставляет создание массива. VS делает топорнее, но вроде не косячит, хотя подозреваю, его проще всего заставить сделать что-то не то в подобном коде...

Comment: @Qwertiy проще всего заставить сделать "что-то не то" (но строго в рамках стандарта) как раз clang

Comment: Но он всё заинлайнил. А вот VS иногда делает `mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rax+4]` (хотя в большинстве случаев там тоже инлайн, но создание и инициализация массива остаётся) - думаю, на основе этого проще получить косяк?

Comment: @Qwertiy всё строго наоборот. Пока компилятор "глупый" и работает в режиме "высокоуровнего ассемблера" - вы можете использовать всяких кулхаки без оглядки на стандарт. Пока типы A и B бинарно совместимы - ничего не поломается. А вот как только компилятор начинает заниматься оптимизацией - стандарт языка резко становится актуален.

Comment: @Qwertiy к примеру, в приведенном мною коде компилятор может доказать что указатели `a+1` и `b+1` ссылаются на разные объекты, а значит на место `a[1].x` можно заинлайнить 5. То, что он не стал доказывать такую сложную теорему, а просто заинлайнил 6 - это просто повезло.

Comment: Есть код: `int a[2]; char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a[0]); p = p + 1`. `p` указывает на `char`, который not similar типу `int`, следовательно выражение `p + 1` является `UB`?

Comment: @wololo, нет, char явно прописан в исключениях - к нему кастить можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так я спрашиваю не про каст, а про наращивание полученного указателя. Что-то в [expr.add/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6) `char` не указан в качестве исключения.