# Нужно ли писать пустой виртуальный деструктор?

Tags: c++, наследование, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Как известно, при необходимости удаления через указатель на родительский класс, класс должен иметь виртуальный деструктор, чтобы оператор `delete` вызвал верный деструктор дочернего класса.

Но что если лично мне вообще не нужен деструктор ни в одном из классов?
Являются ли автоматически сгенерированные деструкторы взаимозаменяемыми?
Или я всё равно обязан добавить виртуальный деструктор в родительский класс?

Насколько я понимаю, генерируется пустой деструктор, поэтому при уничтожении объекта ничего происходить не будет. Да и вообще, компилятор умный и вызов пустой функции выкинет, соответственно, никакой деструктор при удалении вызываться не будет.

В таком случае кажется странным необходимость добавлять виртуальную функцию, которая будет вызываться, если эта функция заведомо является `nop`ом.

https://ideone.com/8ldKsU

```
struct A {
  int x;
  A(unsigned x) : x(x) {}
};

struct B : A
{
  B() : A(7) {}
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new B();
  delete a;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос на enSO - [Virtual Default Destructors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827196/virtual-default-destructors-in-c)

Comment: дублирование?
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764696/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Чем, по Вашему, этот вопрос отличается от предыдущего Вашего вопроса? Ответ на него будет тот же самый.

Comment: @ixSci, там есть деструктор. Здесь же в обоих случаях у меня нет моего деструктора - никакого - ни вритуального, ни невиртуального. Компилятор генерирует пустой, насколько я понимаю. Всегда думал, что в таком случае городить виртуальную функцию не надо?

Comment: Прочтите внимательно цитату, что Ant привёл — там всё есть. У Вас, в сущности, два вопроса об одном и том же. Виртуальным деструктор может стать только при наследовании или явном указании, больше никак. Компилятор генерирует деструктор, который должен удалить все объекты, т.е. «пустой» это не верно в общем случае. Но это всё лирика, т.к. код в вопросе даёт неопределённое поведение согласно стандарту.

Comment: @ixSci, во, кстати, а давай ты лучше ответом напишешь, что неверно полагать, что сгенерированный деструктор является пустым, а следовательно их вообще нельзя считать одинаковыми? Получишь галочку :) А то вопросы всё-таки довольно сильно разные, хотя и оба о виртуальном деструкторе.

Comment: Это будет ответ на другой вопрос, всё же. Пусть просто остаётся закрытым, эти вопросы правда одинаковые.

Comment: @ixSci, это два совершенно разных частных случая - в этом вопорсе я предполгал, что деструктор nop, соответственно никакой деструктор вообще вызываться не будет, а в том вопросе - что если ничего не изменилось в классе, то и деструкторы будут одинаковыми, поэтому при вызове отработают корректно. Давай я дополню вопрос, чтобы такой ответ больше ему соответствовать, потому что с моей точки зрения, эти вопросы совершенно разные.

Comment: @ixSci, я дополнил вопрос своими рассуждениями, прошу ответить, что они неверны.

Comment: Для этого вопрос должен пройти процедуру переоткрытия. Я считаю, что этого делать не нужно, и ответ есть в другом вопросе. Если пользователи посчитают иначе — вопрос откроют. Но Вы это сами прекрасно знаете.

Comment: @ixSci, ты единолично закрыл как обладатель золотого знака. Я бы мог так же переоткрыть как модератор. И ты бы тоже мог. Участия других пользователей я что-то пока не заметил.

Comment: Да, я закрыл и считаю это верным. Ответ на вопрос есть в другом вопросе. В Вашем коде неопределённое поведение. Больше говорить тут не о чем. У Вас уже 3 вопроса на одну и ту же тему. Зачем их плодить, когда можно просто прочитать одну цитату Antа, приведённую в самом начале его ответа?

Comment: @ixSci, ну пор указатели-то вообще другой - там ничего про деструкторы нет. А этот вообще возник из-за комментария alexolut'а к вопорсу про указатели. Кстати, надо его подправить, вероятно, чтоб там было только обсуждаемое UB.

Comment: В его текущей форме вопрос не кажется мне дубликатом. // Надеюсь, я не начинаю войну открытий/закрытий. Заранее сорри.

Comment: Хотя _ответ_ на другой вопрос, кажется, подходит к этому.

Comment: @VladD, мне здесь хочется услышать ответ про непустой конструктор.

Comment: @ixSci, напишешь ответ?

Comment: @Vlad открыл, он пусть и отвечает. Если бы я считал, что этот вопрос нуждается в ответе, то не закрывал бы его изначально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос по сути совпадает с [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764697/10105). Виртуальным деструктор может стать только при наследовании или явном указании, больше никак. Компилятор генерирует деструктор, который должен удалить все объекты, т.е. «пустой» это не верно в общем случае. В стандарте нет исключений для этого случая, код в вопросе даёт неопределённое поведение согласно стандарту.

Дополнительно, пустой с точки зрения исходного кода деструктор на деле не является пустым, в него вкладывается логика по деаллокации экземпляра класса. Поэтому деструкторы разных классов по сути являются разными, не взаимозаменяемыми.

Answer (score 1):

> Как известно, при необходимости удаления через указатель на
>   родительский класс, класс должен иметь виртуальный деструктор, чтобы
>   оператор delete вызвал верный деструктор дочернего класса.

Если дело дошло до виртуальных функций и до удаления объекта по указателю на базовый класс, то рекомендуется писать виртуальные деструкторы, хотя бы и пустые. Потом меньше возни будет их добавлять.

Опять же любая программа имеет тенденцию стать библиотекой и в таком качестве следующие пользователи начинают производить свои классы от Ваших классов. Тут и пригодится виртуальный деструктор.

Что касается приведенного примера, то в нем нет ни виртуальных функций, ни НЕОБХОДИМОСТИ удалять объект класса по по указателю на базовый класс. В качестве иллюстрации того, что в С++ МОЖНО обойтись и без виртуальных деструкторов такой пример имеет право на существование. Но в реальном коде с более-менее развитой системой иерархии классов виртуальные деструкторы must have.