# Что делает строка virtual ~Figure() {};?

Tags: c++

```
class Figure {
public:
    virtual double Square() = 0;
    virtual void   Print() = 0;
    virtual ~Figure() {};
};
```

Что делает эта строка:

```
virtual ~Figure() {};
```

Comment: объявляет и определяет ничего не делающий виртуальный деструктор, причем `;` в конце лишняя

Comment: @VTT А для чего "~"?

Comment: Это запись для деструктора `~ИмяКласса`, а без `~` был бы конструктор

Comment: ААаааа - понял, спасибо

Comment: Вопрос про виртуальный деструктор - один из самых распространённых на собеседованиях.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, обрати внимание на эти вопросы: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764922/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764696/178988 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764692/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начало просто запомните одно правило: *если у вас в классе наследнике есть хотя одно поле с нетривиальным деструктором, деструктор также следует сделать виртуальным.*  Давайте же теперь разберемся из-за чего сформулировалось данное правило... Предлагаю взять самый банальный пример, который описывается практически во всех книгах по языку С++:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base () { cout << "Base()" << endl; }
    ~Base () { cout << "~Base()" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base  {
public:
    Derived () { cout << "Derived()" << endl; }
    ~Derived () { cout << "~Derived()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В ходе выполнения данного кода, мы получим следующее:

```
Base()
Derived()
~Derived()
~Base()
```

Результат программы получился ожидаемым, за единственным исключением того, что сначала конструируется базовая часть класса, затем производная, а при разрушении наоборот — сначала вызывается деструктор производного класса, который по окончании своей работы вызывает по цепочке деструктор базового. Но, что если нам создать этот объект в динамической памяти, использую при этом указатель на объект базового класса:

```
int main()
{
    Base* base = new Derived;
    delete base;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

А вот в этот раз, при выполнении данной программы мы получим совершенно не то, что ожидали, а именно:

```
Base()
Derived()
~Base()
```

Здесь также конструируется объект так, как и надо, но вот при разрушении происходит не то что ожидалось, а именно утечка памяти, потому как деструктор производного класса не вызывается. Причина данного поведения в том, что удаление производится через указатель на базовый класс и для вызова деструктора компилятор использует раннее связывание. Деструктор базового класса не может вызвать деструктор производного, потому что он о нем ничего не знает. В итоге часть памяти, выделенная под производный класс, безвозвратно теряется. Думаю у вас уже появился вопрос, на тему того, что же можно сделать, чтобы избежать этого. Ответ на этот вопрос будет очень простым, чтобы избежать данной проблемы, деструктор в базовом классе должен быть **виртуальным**.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base () { cout << "Base()" << endl; }
    virtual ~Base () { cout << "~Base()" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base  {
public:
    Derived () { cout << "Derived()" << endl; }
    ~Derived () { cout << "~Derived()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base* base = new Derived;
    delete base;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Теперь-то мы наконец получим ожидаемый нами результат:

```
Base()
Derived()
~Derived()
~Base()
```

Осталось, разобраться только почему виртуальный деструктор избавил нас от этой проблемы. А все из-за того, что теперь отныне для вызова деструктора используется позднее связывание, то есть при разрушении объекта берется указатель на класс, затем из таблицы виртуальных функций определяется адрес нужного нам деструктора, а это деструктор производного класса, который после своей работы, как и полагается, вызывает деструктор базового. Также, не стоит забывать и о *виртуальных функциях в деструкторе*, но я уже здесь не буду затрагивать эту тему, так как ответ получится очень большим.

**Лирическое отступление:** Даже после такого подробного объяснения, у вас скорее всего еще останется много различных вопросов и недопониманий различных тонкостей и нюансов с "виртуальностью" в С++. Но чтобы уже окончательно разложить все по полочкам, советую вам основательно разобраться c моделью размещения объектов, а также о позднем и раннем связывании:

[О модели размещения объектов(Часть 1)](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/29/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx)

[О модели размещения объектов(Часть 2)](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/02/objects_memory_layout_p2.aspx)

[О позднем и раннем связывании](https://habr.com/post/51229/)

Надеюсь мой ответ оказался вам полезным, желаю удачи в изучении С++!

Comment: Не учел этого, спасибо за замечание, сейчас исправлю)

Comment: @pavel, вроде бы пришли к выводу, что всегда надо, если объект будет уничтожаться через указатель на родительский тип: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764922/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764696/178988 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764692/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо. похоже я тут был неправ.

Answer (score 0):

Данная запись означает описание деструктора для имени класса `Figure`.
Деструктор имеет такое же имя как и класс только со знаком тильда(~).

Про слово virtual в вышенаписанной строке:
"Виртуальная функция — это функция, объявленная с ключевым словом virtual в базовом классе и переопределенная в одном или в нескольких производных классах."

В фигурных скобках так же могут быть записаны элементы, которые были созданы с помощью `new` тогда, в фигурных скобках необходимо записать `delete` и после указание на объект.

Пример вызова деструктора:

```
class Foo {
 public:
   Foo(const char *name) { m_len = strlen(name); m_name = new char[m_len+1]; strcpy(name, m_name); m_name[m_len] = '\0'; }
   ~Foo() { delete [] m_name; }

  private:
    int m_len;
    char *m_name;
};
```

(пример взят из вики)